# How to use pcap in python to capture other's traffic in same wifi?

Tags: python, pcap, packet-capture, sniffing

It's the first time I use monitor mode in pcap. I think I start the monitor mode successfully since I can see that there is an "eye" symbol on wifi.
However, I still cannot capture packets not sent to me :(
I use handle but not sure how it works and how can I capture those packets not sent to me.

Answer (score 1):

PCAP will only display traffic sent to you. This is true of any sniffer, the software needs to be able to see the traffic. In order to see WiFi traffic that is not sent to you, you will need a WiFi adapter that supports monitor mode. Approx 90% of WiFi adapters, or more, do not support monitor mode. Both the hardware has to be capable to enter the RFMON mode and the driver for the adapter needs to support monitor mode. If monitor mode is set up correctly, you will see 802.11 management traffic (beacons, probes, etc). I don't think monitor mode will show you actual data traffic but I am not sure and maybe it's only my adapter that doesn't show it. If you can see data where the source and dest MAC address are not the MAC address of your adapter and not FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF (broadcast) than you are using monitor mode. I don't know which OS you are using and I don't know what handle is (program name?) so I can't help there. I would suggest that you set the adapter into monitor mode and than verify by running wireshark on the device and look at the traffic. If that works you can go back to PCAP and debug from there.

If you are using Linux and your adapter supports monitor mode, you can enable it by running the following commands as root

`ip link set wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ip link set wlan0 promisc on
ip link set wlan0 up`

Note that if a adapter is in monitor mode, it cannot be connected to a local WiFi network. The adapter would need to be in managed mode where the WiFi AP manages what type of data an adapter receives (frequency, channel, etc). If you are connected to a local WLAN via the adapter than you are not in monitor mode.

Oh! I think I remember hearing somewhere that WinPCAP doesn't support monitor mode. I don't use Windows so you may want to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

Generally will the router just send the packets to you which are addressed to you. This includes packets to you directly or broadcast messages. The messages sent to other devices in the network are not reaching your machine at all, therefore it's impossible to capture it.

If you really have to monitor the whole network traffic you need to get somewhere inbetween the router and the network. Or you could try a man in the middle attack on your wifi.

Comment: I think there is a monitor mode can do so.. But the documents of pcap package are quite difficult to find...

Comment: your router needs a monitor mode, not pcap. pcap can just monitor what you receive on your computer. since you don't receive packets addressed to someone else. generally you could try to capture it with a software like wireshark. Everything you can see with wireshark you could capture with pcapy and nothing more. 
for the documentation of pcap. Try to look for libpcap. pcap is just a python wrapper for it.

Comment: @Memnon In a wireless network you receive all packets sent to everyone. WiFi uses omni directional antennas. A WiFi AP does not know which direction, distance or elevation a receiving device is at. There is no physical way for it to only be able to send packets to one computer. You are probably thinking of a wired network using a switch, which will only send non broadcast packets to the port where the IP-MAC mapping matches the recipient. Also, this doesn't really have anything to do with a router or routing on a LAN. Routers / routing are for non local traffic determined by the subnet mask.